# Why I got LocalTime error on Android/Kotlin but I didn't plain Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, java-time

I've tried this library on plain Kotlin, it's working well. But when I've tried on Android, it doesn't work anymore. Why? What is the difference between codes that I wrote on Kotlin and Android/Kotlin? What is the connection between an API and Java library?

Error on Logcat:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> Ljava/time/LocalTime;

The line I got error is:

```
val current = LocalTime.now().hour
```

Comment: does your java and kotlin target same java compile version? you might also need to add desugaring https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support to use those classes on all android versions

Comment: Okay thanks now that's worked good. But why? Why we need that? Why we can not use Local Time library directly? And when I have to implement this technic?

Comment: Let me put as answer explaining why

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried this library on plain Kotlin, it's working well. But when
> I've tried on Android, it doesn't work anymore. Why?

[Java 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) introduced new Date and time classes (and a lot of other utiility classes), previously developers mostly used [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) a third party library as the built-in java date classes where not reliable and limited in functionality. By default the java and kotlin compilers targets java 6 which is max supported upto android 25 (Nougat).

> What is the connection between an API and Java library?

An api is built into the target device and alibrary has to be shipped with your app.

> What is the difference between codes that I wrote on Kotlin and
> Android/Kotlin

There is not much difference between the java and kotlin compiler, only the target jvm's. Though the kotlin compiler will usually compile code that will fail to run later as it heavily relies on annotations (which you setup)

Depending on your environment (target 6 or 8 for kotlin and java) and your devices (android version 25 and below or above 26) the code will have different classes available to it and setting the target jvm will allow consistancy across android versions.

Comment: Thanks but still I don't understand. Why I've used "desugaring"? And what is the connection with Java 6 & Java 8 and Android API? Okay, I know API and Java interrelated. The Java version was same that I've used on Kotlin project and Android project. So why I've used "desugaring" actually it's the main question. How can I ask different way I don't know. It's may be due to my bad english. Thanks again. Properties from my Android project :Target SDK = 29, Minimum SDK = 19, Source Compatibility = $JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8, Target Compatibility = $JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

Comment: @Furkan Refer to this article https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/support-for-newer-java-language-apis-bca79fc8ef65 and if you are answered please mark as answer. The differences between kotlin and Java and how their compilers work is not easy to put in a single answer and that page might help clarify